# VS code live Sass compiler not generating css file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

Checked at least 10 different sources for a solution but cant find anything that helps. As you can see in the pics, I have a path specified in settings.json but it's not generating a css file in the specified css folder when I click "Watch Sass".

[picture 1 of vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rieCX.jpg)

[picture 2 of vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAftv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says:

```
in file: practise.scss
variable '$light-color' isn't defined
```

Just define `$light-color` (actual line 14) before you call it (actual line 9).